# remove Laravel 4.2 /public from url

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I uploaded my laravel 4.2 project on my shared webhost. now I have to go to `mydomain.com/public` to see the view . But I dont want ant `public` folder in my address . I used so many suggested .htaccess files but they didn't work for me.

Does any one know other solutions ? (not using .htaccess file) ... for example any laravel config that can help me...

thanks

Comment: Laravel is built in a way that all of the files site outside of the root, that way you can point the domain using cPanel/Webmin or whatever control panel you use to /public. It's an added bit of security.

Comment: Maybe , But I dont really like that public in my address . how to get rid of it ?

Comment: That's the point, if you're using virtual hosts and pointing it to /public, then the /public will never be in the URL.

Comment: @Karl and I'm not using virtual hosts ! as I mentioned , its shared domain ! I just can access folders and databases

Comment: What do you mean by a "shared domain"?

Comment: Sorry ! shared Hosting

Comment: Exposing the root of your project is a security hole. Modifying your Laravel code to accept this folder structure is bad, mmmkay. Change hosting to someone that supports running the software you want to use. (There are companies that sells small virtual servers for 5 dollars per month...)

Comment: Whats your document root? is it public_html?

Comment: @Mithredate Nope. its a folder with my domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you need the htaccess file to point to the public folder. But you can copy the content of the public folder in your root folder and change the app path to it.

Copy your index file in your root folder and add this to your index.php file:

```
// set the public path to this directory
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

Comment: as I said , I dont want to use htaccess to do that for me . can you give more explanation on second way ?

Comment: I found one solution , which is similar to yours , so I didnt test your solution but It really seems to be right . thanks

Comment: -1 This is a terrible thing for security. Some files outside the public folder should not be exposed, like the .env file (if used), the .git folder (if used), the storage folder (containing sessions and logs).

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution I recently found and worked on my local host (I wish and think this works on shared webhost too). I hope it helps someone if has the same problem :

laravel 4 remove public from the URL

Follow the steps below to achieve this.

**Step 1**

Move everything from public folder to the root directory

**Step 2**

Now delete the empty ‘public’ folder.

**Step 3**

Edit the file **bootstrap/paths.php**

Find the following line

`'public' => __DIR__.'/../public'`,

and replace it with:

`'public' => __DIR__.'/..'`,

**Step 4**

Modify **index.php** in **root**

Find the following line

`require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php'`;

and replace it with:

`require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php'`;

Now in the same file find the following line

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
```

and replace it with:

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/start.php';
```

That’s all. Browse to your Laravel installation without public in the URL and make sure it works.

Comment: -1 This is a terrible thing for security. This may expose the .git folder (if you publish it; all git commits including source code and history), will expose the storage folder (containing logs and session data), the .env file (if used; production credentials and similar). And those are just things at the top of my mind.

Comment: @SimonSvensson Do you have any suggestions ? FYI : Why should I want to push or pull it anymore ? its done ! I just upload my files to host and this does everything for me !

Comment: Some deployment solutions will ssh into your production server and git pull a deploy-branch. You can then `git log` to see what version you have in production, `git diff` to see if there are any unexpected changes, etc. Files uploaded over ftp may be interrupted from a bad internet connection, or perhaps you just forget to upload everything. Always avoid humans when doing important stuff (like deploying to production environments).